# Extend periods of silence in mp3 files

Tags: mp3, edit

I have a bunch of mp3 files containing lots (about 300 per file) of small (0.5s to 3s long) snippets of audio separated by 1s of silence.

I want to edit these mp3 files (preferably losslessly) so that the silent portion of 1s gets replaced by a period of silence as long as the previous audio snippet + 2s. Example:

Current state of the file:

```
2.3s audio
1.0s silence
1.7s audio
1.0s silence
0.9s audio
1.0s silence
```

Desired:

```
2.3s audio
4.3s silence
1.7s audio
3.7s silence
0.9s audio
2.9s silence
```

What ways are there to achieve this? I'm open for all kinds of suggestions. (GUI application, command line tool, shell script, whatever...)

Comment: Any recommendation on a language? Are there languages particularly suited for audio processing? Or can you recommend some library which is capable of this?

Comment: audio is usually done in c or c++, but in this case performance is not an issue. so use whatever you like that has a library for reading and writting wave files.

Comment: I'd recommend using Matlab or Octave. Solving this task would be rather trivial in these environments and probably among the most effective methods. The procedure would be something like: 1. store all snippets individually, 2. create a new vector of zeros with the correct length, 3. successively write individual snippets at the correct position in the new vector (leaving a 'pause' of your desired length between them). Most challenging would be to implement the detector to find snippets within a file, but even that requires probably only 5 lines of code at most.

Comment: You might not need a script to do this; Sox has some mechanism for detecting silence.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather complicated but can be done with some effort ...

Cubase 5 has a feature called [Detect silence (page 216)](https://www.scribd.com/doc/29375882/Operation-Manual-Cubase-5) that will mark or split the file for you automagically - from there you will be able to shorten the events & move each event **by hand** ...

then you can design a macro command that will separate each event from the last using the selected event witch will require selecting each separate event and pressing a button ...

---

**Macro:**

Transport - Location to selection

Edit - Insert silence

---

then grab all of the events and drag them to the start of the grid ...

> Jobs that ant workers do ...

Answer (score 0):

This is well within Audacity's capabilities. Make sure you get it (free) from the [official site](https://www.audacityteam.org/). There are a lot of sites packing adware and worse with the application.